# How do you change the style of a text box? (HTML / CSS)

Tags: html, css, forms, formatting, textbox

How do you change the style of a text box from the default. For instance, so it looks like:

[alt text http://www.wiggle100.com/Untitled-2.png](http://www.wiggle100.com/Untitled-2.png)

or

[alt text http://www.wiggle100.com/Untitled-3.png](http://www.wiggle100.com/Untitled-3.png)

instead of:

[alt text http://www.wiggle100.com/Untitled-1.png](http://www.wiggle100.com/Untitled-1.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theoretically you can write a style rule like:

```
input[type=text] {
    border: 4px solid purple;
}
```

However, the `[type=text]` syntax is not cross-browser compatible.  I generally add a `text` class to the input, like so;

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="foo" />
```

Then you can write a traditional CSS rule like:

```
input.text {
    border: 4px solid purple;
}
```

Of course, this assumes you want four pixel solid purple borders.  Adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The border CSS attribute is what I think you're looking for.  See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533532(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The input fields in your screenshot have not actually been styled, they look like the OS defaults. Instead, the designer has opted to style the parent elements such as the `form`, `fieldset` and possible `div`s or `lists` for positioning.

[This article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms/) will give you a great foundation for building prettier forms.